# Undefined class constant fix

Tags: php

I'm coding a website in php but when I tested it, the page indicates HTTP ERROR 500. So I searched for the problem and I found a log file which indicated me the following content:

> 'ERR_WARNING' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SITE/config/connect.php:3
>    Stack trace:
>    #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SITE/config/functions.php(5): require()
>    #1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SITE/index.php(4): getArticles()
>    #2 {main}
>    thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SITE/config/connect.php on line 3

Then I checked the file functions.php but found no errors could you please help me fix this problem.

Here is my functions.php file:

```
<?php
// ARTICLE FUNCTION
    function getArticles()
    {
        require "./config/connect.php";
        $req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT id, title FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC');
        $req->execute();
        $data = $req->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        return $data;
        $req->closeCursor();
    }
?>
```

Here is my connect.php file:

```
<?php 
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blog;charset=utf8','root','root'); 
    $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERR_WARNING); 
?>
```

Then, I placed the replace command in function.php under the close cursor one, however, it didn't solve the problem

Then, I changed the password in my connect file and in my database so that they are now the same one.

But it didn't solve the problem showing me the following message:

> [09-Apr-2019 15:15:31 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: >YES) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SITE/config/connect.php:2
>   Stack trace:
>   #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SITE/config/connect.php(2): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', '123')
>   #1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SITE/config/functions.php(5): require('/Applications/M...')
>   #2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SITE/index.php(4): getArticles()
>   #3 {main}
>    thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SITE/config/connect.php on line 2

Then, I realised that the password I put in the connect file was wrong and I changed it. It took me back to the first error:

> [09-Apr-2019 16:40:18 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'ERR_WARNING' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SITE/config/connect.php:3
>   Stack trace:
>   #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SITE/config/functions.php(5): require()
>   #1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SITE/index.php(4): getArticles()
>   #2 {main}
>     thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/SITE/config/connect.php on line 3

Comment: As I'm using a mac device I don't think this method will work

Comment: Glad you solved your problem, but there is no need to mark questions as resolved. See [why we remove “solved” from question titles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311829).

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution. 
In the connect file my line 3 was:

```
$bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERR_WARNING);
```

However there was a typo: constant `ERR_WARNING` doesn't exist – it should be: `ERRMODE_WARNING`. Replacing that constant  with the correct name  fixed the problem:

```
$bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
```

Thank you for all your answers and excuse to have bothered your time for this simple problem